# Spring MVC and html input

Tags: spring-mvc

In Spring 3.1 Web MVC form I am using following field take the date from datepicker and the field defined in form as `String`. I am getting all the values but I am not getting the date field.

**First Try**

```
<form:input id="fromDate" class="mydate" path="fromDate" size="10" maxlength="10" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        Spring.addDecoration(new Spring.ElementDecoration({elementId : 'fromDate', widgetType : 'dijit.form.DateTextBox', widgetAttrs : {promptMessage: 'Enter From Date', invalidMessage: 'Please enter valid From Date', required: false, constraints: {datePattern : 'dd/MM/yyyy', required : false}, datePattern : 'dd/MM/yyyy'}}));
    </script>
```

**Second Try**

```
<input id="toDate" class="mydate" path="toDate" size="10" maxlength="10" />
    <spring:bind path="schemeQuantity.toDate">
        ${status.value}
    </spring:bind>
    <script type="text/javascript">
```

Is it possible to use simple HTML input tag and bound with Spring MVC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible to use simple html input tag.
In the form tag add a `commandName` attribute like this

```
<form:form commandName="attribute" name="createForm" id="createForm" acceptCharset="UTF-8" method="post" action="create">
```

Now in your controller class add `@ModelAttribute` like this.

```
@RequestMapping(value="create" , method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String createAttribute( Model model , @ModelAttribute YourPojoClass attribute,Errors errors)
```

Comment: I am not able to understand createAttribute. Is the method to serve the request or it is the separate method create attribute.

Comment: Its just a method name..nothing else.. :)

Comment: @ModelAttribute("schemeQuantity")
    public SchemeQuantity getSchemeQuantity()
    {
  SchemeQuantity schemeQuantity = new SchemeQuantity();
  schemeQuantity.setQuantityRules(new AutoPopulatingList<QuantityRule>(QuantityRule.class));
  //.setStudents(new AutoPopulatingList(Student.class));
  return schemeQuantity;
    }   is it fine  am I need to add in method as well.

Comment: Tell me one thing. Are you trying to get the values from UI or the other way round?